# How to change background color of Dropdown in TimePicker and font color - MUI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timepicker

I'm trying to change some properties like background color and font color in TimePicker using the css className properties, but with no success. Does anyone knows how to do this and where can I find a docummentation with these properties?

```
<TimePicker
          ampm={false}
          views={['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']}
          sx={{
            backgroundColor: "#333335",
            font: "white",
            color: "#FFFF",
            textDecoration: "bold",
            input: {
              color: "#FFFF",
              fontSize: "1.4rem",
            },
              "& .MuiTimePicker-root": {
              backgroundColor: "#222223",
            },
            "& .MuiTimePicker-input": {
              color: "#FFFF",
              fontSize: "1.2rem",
            },
          }}
          value={selectedTime}
          onChange={(newTime: any) => setSelectedTime(newTime)}
          timeSteps={{hours: 1, minutes: 1, seconds: 1}}
        />
```

[TimePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzkFu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slotProps` in TimePicker.

For example:

```
<TimePicker
  /* { ...restProps } */
  slotProps={{
    popper: {
      sx: {
        "& .MuiList-root": {
          backgroundColor: "yellow",
        },
        "& .MuiMenuItem-root": {
          "&.Mui-selected": {
             backgroundColor: "green",
             color: "blue"
          },
          color: "red"
        },
        "& .MuiDialogActions-root": {
          backgroundColor: "black",
        },
      },
    },
  }}
/>;
```

You can see the whole example here: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-resonance-mqqdqw?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Hi Victor, thank you for provider the solution! Do you know what's the property of font Color on dropdown time numbers? From what documentation did you got this css tags?

Comment: @lucasnatanmelo - I updated my answer. please check it. And I found CSS tags from chrome dev tools. ; )

Comment: Hello @Victor! Could you help one more time? Do you know what is the property to change the clock icon color that is shown in Timepicker input? I can't change the default black color. Thank's if you could help me again.

Comment: Hi @lucasnatanmelo, thank you for your comment. I'm glad you found my answer helpful. However, your question is not related to the original question, which was about changing the clock icon color in Timepicker input. It is better to ask a new question with a clear title and description, rather than adding a new question as a comment to an existing answer. This way, you can avoid confusion and get more relevant and specific answers from the community. Of course, I can help you.

Comment: Hello @Pluto - Victor. Could you please help me in this question that I did from MUI lib too? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76899438/how-to-change-height-make-width-responsive-and-change-fontcolor-text-field-when